# Padding for Inline Elements

Tags: css, w3c

I am reading a book about CSS basics. It is claimed in the book that an inline element has complete padding properties but no **margin-top/bottom** properties, only **margin-left/right** properties.

My first question is, where can I find this as an official statement? I found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visudet.html#q15) that if **margin-top/bottom** is set to `auto` then it is set to `0`. But isn't that different from saying **margin-top/bottom** does not apply to inline-elements?

My second question is, does an inline element really got complete padding properties? I tried the following example:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> </head>

<body>
  <div style="margin: 20px; border: solid 20px;background: red;">
    <p style="margin:0">
      test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
      <strong style="padding:20px;background-color:yellow">hello</strong> test test test test
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now, this shows that padding actually works somehow, but for some reason, `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` has no effect on the surrounding text. Why is that? Is this mentioned anywhere in the W3 standards?

Comment: You ask about margin but give an example of padding? Your question you state "inline element has complete padding properties" and your example shows that, so what is your question.

Comment: @Leeish and also the example shows that padding only works 50%. The background color is applied to padding-top, but padding-top has no influence at the surrounding text. Therefore I claim that padding is not working as expected.

Comment: See my answer. It is adding padding to the `strong` element. But inline elements don't have a `height` as block and inline-block elements do. They don't affect the height of their parents like a block element as the `height` of an inline element is it's line-height as per 10.6.1 which you linked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It is claimed in the book that an inline element has complete padding
>   properties but no margin-top/button properties, only margin-left/right
>   properties.
>
> My first question is, where can I find this as an official statement?

You won't, because it isn't quite true. In the [box model](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/box.html#propdef-margin-top) it says that for margin-top and margin-bottom:

> These properties have no effect on non-replaced inline elements.

But "no effect" does not mean that the properties don't exist. Specifically, they do exist for the purposes of inheritance. Consider this example:

```css
p { border:1px solid red }
i { vertical-align:top; }
span { margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;  }
b { display:inline-block; }
.two { margin:inherit;  }
```

```html
<p><i>Hello</i> <span>World <b class="one">my good friend</b></span></p>
<p><i>Hello</i> <span>World <b class="two">my good friend</b></span></p>
```

We can see that the b element with class "two" inherits the margin top and bottom properties of the inline, non-replaced span element, and since that b element is inline-block, the margin-top and bottom do cause a layout difference. That would be impossible if the margin-top and bottom properties did not exist on the span.

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is, where can I find this as an official statement?
>   I found here that if margin-top/bottom is set to 'auto' then it is set
>   to '0'. But isn't that different from saying 'margin-top/botton does
>   not apply to inline-elements'?

In 8.1 Box Model Spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin) "The margin edge surrounds the box margin. If the margin has 0 width(height), the margin edge is the same as the border edge."

In the page you linked 10.6.1 "The 'height' property doesn't apply, but the height of the box is given by the 'line-height' property." So since height doesn't apply, then the margin-edge is the same as the border edge.

> My second question is, does an inline element really got complete
>   padding properties? I tried the following example:

Same reason as above. "the height of the box is given by the 'line-height' property". The height of that strong element is set by the `line-height` as it has no height to reference as a block or inline-block element would. I'm pretty sure if you gave it inline-block properties it would as a block has height in the model.

Comment: Thank you. Still, I am new to the WC3 documentation and thats probably why I do not understand your conclusions. Here is my first problem: I see that it is said in 10.6.1 ***If margin-top is set to 'auto', then it is set to 0***. I have the feeling that you say ***Whatever margin-top is assigned to, it will be set to 0*** but I do not find this statement.

Comment: Right after "their computed value is 0" it says "The 'height' property doesn't apply, but the height of the box is given by the 'line-height' property."  So follow me, if the 'height' property doesn't apply then per the box model in 8.1 which I linked then the height of the box is only set by the `line-height` at least that's the way I understand it.

Answer (score -1):

> but for some reason it has no effect on the surrounding text

Try substituting `margin` for `padding` at `strong` element, adding `display:inline-block` to `strong` style

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="margin: 20px;
          border: solid 20px;
          background: red;">
    <p style='margin:0'>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
      <strong style="margin:20px;background-color:yellow;display:inline-block;">hello</strong>
      test test test test</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to prove that the inline element has no margin-top/bottom? Because then I don't see your point, since background-color only applies to padding, not to margin.

Comment: @Adam Post intends to apply `margin`  to `strong` element where surrounding text appear affected by `margin` property , by including `display:inline-block` to `strong` element . If inspect `strong` element without `inline-block` applied , `margin-top` , `margin-bottom` is still applied to element - with `display` set to `inline` . Though element does not have `inline-block` or `block` `display` applied , which would visually affect surrounding text