# How to keep a row of buttons neatly spaced on a small screen

Tags: html

If the html code below is run on a small screen, one or more buttons will naturally move on to the "lower line", adjusting to screen size. In principle that's great but unfortunately any button moving from the row will be glued to a button above. That... is ugly and less functional.

How can I space them vertically?

```html
<style>

.button {
    background: #fcfcfc;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    font: large;
    color: ButtonText;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 12px 5px 12px;
    border: solid #b8a8a8 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
    border: solid #7b6b6b 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

</style>

<center>

<div class="container">
    <a href="https://www.archive.org/" class="button">Archive 1</a>
    <a href="https://www.archive.org/" class="button">Archive 2</a>
    <a href="https://www.archive.org/" class="button">Archive 3</a>
    <a href="https://www.archive.org/" class="button">Archive 4</a>
</div>

</center>
```

Comment: Floats and padding

Comment: thank you for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DanielC for his [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620139/padding-for-inline-elements) I could find the solution. Very simply you only have to add `margin` definitions on `.button` styling. That way the buttons are always neatly arranged, no matter the size of the screen! 8-)

```html
<style>

.button {
    background: #fcfcfc;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    font: large;
    color: ButtonText;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 12px 5px 12px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: solid #b8a8a8 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
    border: solid #7b6b6b 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

</style>

<center>

<div class="container">
    <a href="https://www.archive.org/" class="button">Archive 1</a>
    <a href="https://www.archive.org/" class="button">Archive 2</a>
    <a href="https://www.archive.org/" class="button">Archive 3</a>
    <a href="https://www.archive.org/" class="button">Archive 4</a>
</div>

</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to affect spacing on an inline element (the anchor tag) which isn't as clear-cut as a block element (list item for instance). Try wrapping your anchor tags in a block element and apply the style to the wrapping object. 
Have a look at this post for reference: [Padding for Inline Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620139/padding-for-inline-elements)

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Comment: You want just a padding? What's wrong with this world!!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button {
    background: #fcfcfc;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfcfc, #d6d6d6);
    font: large;
    color: ButtonText;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 12px 5px 12px;
    border: solid #b8a8a8 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
    border: solid #7b6b6b 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .button {
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

```html
<center>

<div class="container">
    <a href="https://www.archive.org/" class="button">Archive 1</a>
    <a href="https://www.archive.org/" class="button">Archive 2</a>
    <a href="https://www.archive.org/" class="button">Archive 3</a>
    <a href="https://www.archive.org/" class="button">Archive 4</a>
</div>

</center>
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because when making the screen small, the buttons pile up on top of each other with no space in between them(on a new browser window). Thanks anyway!