# Breakable colored underline in CSS

Tags: html, css, underline

I would like to have a colored underline that looks like this when it breaks: 
[image: Heading with colored underline in one and two lines]

`text-decoration-color` seems to be not supported widely enough.

I tried this:

```css
.underline {
  position: relative;
 }

.underline:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ffc04d;
  bottom: .1rem;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
 <h1><span class="underline">Sprouted Bread</span></h1>
```

[image: and this is what it looks like when it breaks.]

Comment: Have you looked into [`box-decoration-break: clone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgz9ndme/1/)

By wrapping the elements like you have in a span. You can put the text decoration on the parent element and the text color on the span.

**HTML:**

```
<h1><span class="underline">Some Text</span></h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
}

.underline {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What about a linear-gradient where it will be easy to control color, size and distance within a single element:

```css
.underline {
  position: relative;
  font-size:28px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(yellow,yellow) /* Color */
    left 0 bottom 2px/ /* Position */
    100% 2px  /* Size (width height)*/
    no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<div style="width:150px;text-align:center"><span class="underline">Sprouted Bread</span></div>
```

As a side note, border-bottom works fine used with **inline element** but of course you cannot easily control the distance to make it behave as a text-decoration:

```css
.underline {
  position: relative;
  font-size:28px;
  border-bottom:2px solid yellow;
 }
```

```html
<div style="width:150px;text-align:center"><span class="underline">Sprouted Bread</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Just add a border!

Using `display: inline`, add a bottom border and space it with padding.

You could also use `line-height` and then place negative margins to increase the space in between the lines.

And...you could also animate it!

```css
.underline {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc04d;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="width: 5em">
  <span class="underline">Sprouted Bread</span>
</h1>
```

<sup><strike>As mentioned by @chriskirknielsen, you could use [box-decoration-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break), although not supported by [IE or Edge](https://caniuse.com/#search=box-decoration-break).</strike> Credits: @Temani Afif</sup>

Comment: not sure i followed, but if you remove the property you will also have the same thing no ? because it's an inline element

Comment: well, we dont use padding-bottom/top with inline element as they are rendred outside ... add border to the h1 and use a big padding bottom to see what happen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620139/padding-for-inline-elements?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: you cannot use line-height and margin-top with inline element also :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167214/discussion-between-chris-happy-and-temani-afif).