# How to make navigation button's height larger than its container's height?

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve something like this image:

[image]

Basically the navigation button's height is larger than its container's height.

This is what I so far:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  height:100px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

Could someone please advice on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the navigation elements `inline`and you can easily do this using padding and background. You may refer to this question to understand how it works [Padding for Inline Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620139/padding-for-inline-elements)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  padding:5px;
  margin:20px;
}

.topnav a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks nice, but on hover and for events the other buttons are the same size (just without a background).

Comment: @Programmer tha is actually what I was looking for. ;)