# Margin In Display: Inline DIV's causing them to render into above Display: Block DIV Box

Tags: html, css

Three DIVS
Top two Block
Third Inline
Third contains 4 Nested Inline DIVS

If I add any Padding to either of the Third Inline or 4 Nested Inline DIVs they render up into the second block DIV.

I have read up on Margin Collapsing but given Margin: 0px all elements doesn't seem relevant.
Sure something well known but I am unable to uncover where the behaviour is documented.

Thanks for any knowledge / pointers.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#topEyesGrab {
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#menuBar {
    background-color: SlateBlue;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#mainContent {
    background-color: Violet;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

.mainBoxes {
    background-color: Tomato;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

/* https://www.sitepoint.com/collapsing-margins/ */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/maincss.css"> -->
</head>
<body>

<div id="pageContainer">
    <div id="topEyesGrab">
    Top Eyes Grab
    </div>
    <div id="menuBar">
    Menu Bar
    </div>
    <div id="mainContent">
            <div id="box01" class="mainBoxes">Box 01</div>
            <div id="box02" class="mainBoxes">Box 02</div>
            <div id="box03" class="mainBoxes">Box 03</div>
            <div id="box04" class="mainBoxes">Box 04</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What result do you want to get?

Comment: s.kuznetsov - 1) I'd like to get a set of boxes in a regular pattern as a visual index for content like what you have on the front screen of smart phones. 2) More broadly, I'd also like to understand the algorithm used to generate the box corner positions and z indexes for layouts used on webpages so such behaviour as the one I have discovered can be understood. I expect there is a known rendering pattern at somewhere like W3C or another resource providing same.

Comment: you want an explanation of a fix?

Comment: Temani Afif - I am really keen on an explanation, though see my point 1 above in answer to s.kuznetsov as well.

Comment: explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33620139/8620333

Answer (score 1):

Your `mainContent` is inline but has padding, which leads to the issue. Try setting `mainBoxes` class CSS to `display: inline-block;` may solve it. `inline-block` elements are similar to inline elements, except they can have padding and margins added on all four sides.

For the difference between `inline` and `inline-block`: please refer to [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

> inline-block.
> The element generates a block element box that will be flowed with surrounding content as if it were a single inline box (behaving much like a replaced element would).

However, you may need to update the styles of `mainContent` class as well. `display:inline` seems unnecessary, I commented it out.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#topEyesGrab {
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#menuBar {
    background-color: SlateBlue;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#mainContent {
    background-color: Violet;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    /*display: inline;*/
}

.mainBoxes {
    background-color: Tomato;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* https://www.sitepoint.com/collapsing-margins/ */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/maincss.css"> -->
</head>
<body>

<div id="pageContainer">
    <div id="topEyesGrab">
    Top Eyes Grab
    </div>
    <div id="menuBar">
    Menu Bar
    </div>
    <div id="mainContent">
            <div id="box01" class="mainBoxes">Box 01</div>
            <div id="box02" class="mainBoxes">Box 02</div>
            <div id="box03" class="mainBoxes">Box 03</div>
            <div id="box04" class="mainBoxes">Box 04</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

### why not `display: flex`?

just use `display: flex` on `#mainContent` and remove `display: inline` on `.mainBoxes`.

now you can use both margin and padding on the boxes.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#topEyesGrab {
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#menuBar {
    background-color: SlateBlue;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#mainContent {
    background-color: Violet;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: flex; /*or inline-flex*/
}

.mainBoxes {
    background-color: Tomato;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 8px;
    /*display: inline;*/
}

/* https://www.sitepoint.com/collapsing-margins/ */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/maincss.css"> -->
</head>
<body>

<div id="pageContainer">
    <div id="topEyesGrab">
    Top Eyes Grab
    </div>
    <div id="menuBar">
    Menu Bar
    </div>
    <div id="mainContent">
            <div id="box01" class="mainBoxes">Box 01</div>
            <div id="box02" class="mainBoxes">Box 02</div>
            <div id="box03" class="mainBoxes">Box 03</div>
            <div id="box04" class="mainBoxes">Box 04</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```