# How do I prevent the border of an element consuming its padding in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, chromium

What I want is a text with a background color, underneath some space (e.g. via border-padding in the example) and then a colored underline (via border-bottom in the example).

The following snippet does exactly what I want in Firefox.
However, in Chrome the border seems to "consume" the padding such that there is no space left in between the texts background color and the underline.

```css
#test {
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-clip: content-box;
    -webkit-background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="test">Test div</span>
</div>
```

Is this behavior documented somewhere and more importantly, is there a way to prevent this from happening in Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the `span` a `display:inline-block;` and it will work like in Firefox.

```css
#test {
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-clip: content-box;
    -webkit-background-clip: content-box;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="test">Test div</span>
</div>
```

Explanation: `inline` elements tend to not respect the padding-top (or bottom) leading to some inconsistent cross-browser experience. You can read more at this pretty much the same question: [Padding for Inline Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620139/padding-for-inline-elements)

Comment: This works, thanks! However, in my original problem I have a line-height property set to 200% in the parent div. If I use `display: inline-block` then the element fills the entire line-height which I don't want. Do you have an idea what to do in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure why do you need a 200% line-height? Maybe I could have some ideas if I can see the whole picture.

Comment: I have a long text that stretches over multiple lines and in the text annotations as described in the original question. Now I don't want the annotations on different lines to overlap or be adjacent. See here for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/8t5k3drv/5/ . The first version in Firefox is exactly what I want, but doesn't work in Chrome and in the second version with inline-block  the annotations are stretched too much in the y-axis.

Comment: I hope you're fine with using pseudo-selectors like this: https://jsfiddle.net/phucbm/e6df4L3a/7/. I want to separate the red background and the blue underline so that we can adjust the spacing between them more precisely.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my larger example using pseudo elements destroys the text flow. How I finally solved it is using nested elements, one for the background and one for the underline: https://jsfiddle.net/kyhvcr3t/