# Why is spacing around not loading image removed in Firefox?

Tags: css, image, spacing, alt-attribute

In Firefox, the spacing around images that don't load is removed.

Code to reproduce:

```html
<h2>If image loads, padding is fine</h2>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="alt">

<h2>Firefox issue if image does not load: img is moved upwards</h2>
<img src="broken" alt="alt">

<style>
img {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

| Result in Chrome ✅ | Result in Firefox ❌ |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7vsu5m8q/

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is considering the broken image to be an inline element. In a normal situation, an image is a **replaced inline element** so padding apply to it. Firefox seems to ignore the "replaced" part when there is no image content and consider the image as "inline element" only and padding applied to [inline elements won't affect the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33620139/8620333)

I don't know if it's a correct behavior (need to dig into the Spec) but to overcome this, make the image `inline-block`

```html
<h2>If image loads, padding is fine</h2>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="alt">

<h2>Firefox issue if image does not load: img is moved upwards</h2>
<img src="broken" alt="alt">

<style>
img {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}
```